# Gmod Lua/Sql Error (attempt to concatenate a table value)

Tags: sql, lua

Hey guys I'm having a problem with SQL queries

i have this code:

```
sql.Query("SELECT hp FROM hp_data WHERE steam =  '"..ply:SteamID().."';")
```

This is the error I get:

> "attempt to concatenate a table value"

My table looks like this:

The table is called hp_data

```
 | steam      | hp  | money |

1|STEAM:0_0_0 | 100 | 500   |
```

What can I do to make 
`"sql.Query("SELECT hp FROM hp_data WHERE steam = '"..ply:SteamID().."';")"` return 100 ?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: if you just want to get 100 value from HP then why can't you use money=500 in where condition for this specific record!!

Comment: Money and hp are var's that can change at any time, and steam doesn't change, also, what would be the difference?

Comment: What is `ply:SteamID()`?

Comment: ply:SteamID() returns the steam id of the local player, and is usually something like this: STEAM:x_y_z  check this: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID , im coding for a game called Garry's Mod, it's irrelevant anyway since the query is working, the problem is: it returns a table and I can't pick the value that the hp is equal to

Comment: The ask for what specifically is returned by 'ply:SteamID()' is a reasonable one.  It's clearly not returning a Lua string or you'd not be getting this error (the 'table' referred to is a Lua table data type, not a SQL table).  It may be helpful to assign it as 'foo = ply:SteamID()' and then try printing type(foo) to confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the query, the "concatenation" problem is due to assign a var like

`var = sql.Query("SELECT hp FROM hp_data WHERE steam = '"..ply:SteamID().."';")`

to get the hp value from the database.

You have to do it like this:

```
sql.Query("SELECT hp FROM hp_data WHERE steam = '"..ply:SteamID().."';", function(return)
   return[1].hp_data[1].hp
end)`
```